# For loop input issue

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a for loop that repeats until the user decides to exit but the code only executes once. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
Vegetables = scanner.nextInt();

for (i = 0; i < Vegetables; i++) {
    if (Vegetables == 1) {
        System.out.println("Red Onions $0.10");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 2) {
        System.out.println("Olives $0.10");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 3) {
        System.out.println("Pickles $0.10");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 4) {
        System.out.println("Lettuce $0.20");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 5) {
        System.out.println("Green Peppers $0.25");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 6) {
        System.out.println("Tomatoes $0.30");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 7) {
        System.out.println("Cheese $0.49");
    }
    else if (Vegetables == 8) {
        System.out.println("End of selection");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Entry must be between 1 through 8.");
    }
```

Comment: Your loop is over `i`, but your `if` chain only compares `Vegetables`... which is also the loop terminating condition. If `i >= Vegetables` do not enter the loop at all. In short, this code does not make any sense.

Comment: i don't get why a `for` loop is used here. It's so obvious that `while(condition)` the the natural way. I mean, where do you read again the user input right now? Nowhere, right? And how would you know when to stop the `for` loop?

Comment: and if the user enters 0, the loop will never be executed ... so the user would never see the warning that it has to be between 1 and 8

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop will only ever execute a set number of times. That is the point of such a loop.

If you want to continue the loop until a certain condition is met, you need to use a `while` or `do/while` loop instead.

For example, you could change your loop to be something like this:

```
while (Vegetable != 8) {
  // get the user's selection
}
```